# Error in model.frame.default : variable lengths differ

Tags: r

I'm having trouble with a linear regression in R and I can't figure out what the problem is:

My code:

```
*# Clear the global environment
rm(list = ls())
# Upload the data
data <- read.csv("info.csv", sep = ",", header = TRUE)
#function 
  linear_model <- function(x){
    summary(lm(formula = x ~ Vegetariana + Vegana + una_comida + dos_comidas + Low + Medium + Delivery))
  }

id_n<- c(id_1,id_2,id_3,id_4,id_5,id_6,id_7,id_8,id_9,id_10,id_11,id_12,id_13,id_14,id_15)

  #FOR LOOP   
for(id in id_n){
    b<- as.numeric(id)
    a <- linear_model(b)
    a
  }*
```

I've also tried with a loop

```
for(i in 1:15){     
     b <- as.numeric(unlist(id_n[i]))
     a <- linear_model(b)
     a
   }
```

Still, not working the loop for the 15 cases I have to run.

Thanks in advance!

PS. id_1 and id_2 are columns in my dataset
if I run the function with

```
     a <- linear_model(id_1)
    a
```

it works perfectly. The point is that I don't want to type the function 15 times.

PS:

```
> dput(data[1:10])
structure(list(Carnivora = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Vegetariana = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), Vegana = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), una_comida = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), dos_comidas = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), comida_refrigerio = c(0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), Low = c(1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Medium = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), High = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), Delivery = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-13L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: try dput(data) or dput(data[1:10,]) and share the output with us so we can run it in our machine and debug it. (do not share data if they can be used to identify people)

Comment: You need to give your data to the model, `lm(formula = x ~ ..., data = data)`

Comment: And are you ignoring an Object Not Found error at your `id_n<- c(id_1,id_2, ...)` line? Those aren't defined anywhere. Even if they are columns in your data, they're **in your data** and not accessible unless you use `data$id_1` or `data[["id_1"]]`.

Comment: @DimitriosZacharatos
> dput(data[1:10])
structure(list(Carnivora = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Vegetariana = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), Vegana = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), una_comida = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), dos_comidas = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L),

Comment: @DimitriosZacharatos (continue)

 comida_refrigerio = c(0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), Low = c(1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Medium = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), High = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), Delivery = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-13L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: @GregorThomas I see what you mean, but I don't know how to code that data$id_1 inside the loop...

Comment: we do not usually put them in the comments section we put the data in the question section :)

Comment: My bad, sorry, rookie mistake